# Go GraphQL client applied to 'hello world' GraphQL server: "struct field for "hello" doesn't exist in any of 1 places to unmarshal"

Tags: json, go, graphql

I'm trying to use the https://github.com/shurcooL/graphql GraphQL client on a simple GraphQL server that I started following the code snippet at https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server#installation-standalone:

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

// The GraphQL schema
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    "A simple type for getting started!"
    hello: String
  }
`;

// A map of functions which return data for the schema.
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'world',
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

I'm trying to use this with the following Go script:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/shurcooL/graphql"
)

var query struct {
    hello graphql.String
}

func main() {
    client := graphql.NewClient("http://localhost:4000", nil)

    if err := client.Query(context.Background(), &query, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", query)
}
```

However, if I try to run this, I get this error:

```
2019/11/21 12:07:21 struct field for "hello" doesn't exist in any of 1 places to unmarshal
exit status 1
```

Any idea what is causing this? I don't see how my implementation deviates from the documentation at https://github.com/shurcooL/graphql.

Comment: query.hello is not an exported name. Try query.Hello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert [Burak Serdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11923999/burak-serdar)'s comment to an answer, `hello` was not an exported name (cf. https://tour.golang.org/basics/3) and I needed to change it to `Hello`:

```
var query struct {
    Hello graphql.String
}
```

Now the program prints

```
{Hello:world}
```